# Weird behavior with multiple conditions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !script.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} url=(.*)
RewriteRule .* script.php?q=%1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !script.php
RewriteRule (.*) script.php?q=$1
```

What I'm trying to accomplish here is that every access to `http://example.com/?url=www.google.com` is redirected to `script.php?q=www.google.com` and if there is no query string, relative path should be sent to `script.php`, for example in `http://example.com/path`,  should be redirected to `script.php?q=path`. This doesn't seem to work with my rules, but I'm not sure why. Is this even possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your rules as this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^url=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ script.php?q=%1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ script.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for the most part, except that relative path may contain query string, just not 'url' as query string..

Comment: Did you forget to specify that in your question? Provide examples of those URLs and how it should be rewritten.